# Operate on part of sequence while returning whole sequence

Tags: python

I want to shorten a python class name by truncating all but the last part ie: `module.path.to.Class` => `mo.pa.to.Class`.

This could be accomplished by splittin the string and storing the list in a variable and then operating on all but the last part and joining them back.

I would like to know if there is a way to do this in one step ie:

- split to parts
- create two copies of sequence (`tee` ?)
- apply truncation to one sequence and not the other
- join selected parts of sequence

Something like:

```
'.'.join( [chain(map(lambda x: x[:2], foo[:-1]), bar[-1]) for foo, bar in tee(name.split('.'))] )
```

But I'm unable to figure out working with `...foo, bar in tee(...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it by splitting, you can split once on the last dot first, and then process only the first part by splitting it again to get the package indices, then shorten each to its first two characters, and finally join everything back together in the end. If you insist on doing it inline:

```
name = "module.path.to.Class"
short = ".".join([[x[:2] for x in p.split(".")] + [n] for p, n in [name.rsplit(".", 1)]][0])
print(short)   # mo.pa.to.Class
```

This creates unnecessary lists just so it can traverse the list comprehension waters safely, in reality it probably ends up being slower than just doing it in a normal, procedural fashion:

```
def shorten_path(source):
    indices = source.split(".")
    return ".".join(x[:2] for x in indices[:-1]) + "." + indices[-1]

name = "module.path.to.Class"
print(shorten_path(name))  # mo.pa.to.Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in one line with a regular expression:

```
>>> re.sub(r'(\b\w{2})\w*(\.)', r'\1\2', 'module.path.to.Class') 
'mo.pa.to.Class'
```

The pattern `r'(\b\w{2})\w*(\.)'` captures two matches: the first two letters of a word, and the dot at the end of the word.

The substitution pattern `r'\1\2'` concatenates the two captured groups - the first two letters of the word and the dot.

No `count` parameter is passed to `re.sub` so all occurrences of the pattern are substituted.

The final word - the class name - is not truncated because it isn't follwed by a dot, so it doesn't match the pattern.